# How can I smooth thousands of faces in a 3D-mesh so as to end up with 6 faces of a die?

Tags: computational-geometry, computer-vision

I have a 3D scan of an object with multiple faces, for example a standard 6 face die. The scan is a point cloud file of the die.
I am able to convert the point cloud into a mesh and retrieve faces from the mesh.

But what I'm not able to figure out is how to smooth the faces so instead of having thousands of faces I end up with 6.
I'm sure this has been done I just can't figure it out.
The solution can be in c++, python, c#... I care more about how :)

Answer (score 2):

First things first, there is no perfect answer to your problem. For samples taken from real sensors, what constitutes "flat" must always be understood with respect to some tolerance.

Also remember that a real-world six-sided die probably has rounded edges and corners, otherwise you could injure yourself with it. It also likely has physical pips. You have to make a *lot* of assumptions to get six flat faces from a scan.

I'm going to give you a few options, and this should give you enough information to look through the literature for other options.

Option 1: Search for planes in the raw pointcloud.

You can do this using a technique such as the [Hough transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hough_transform) or [RANSAC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_sample_consensus). Using RANSAC as our example, picking three points at random defines a plane, and once you have a candidate plane, you can then test all the other points to see which ones fit the same plane (e.g. using least-squares distance). If enough points are "inliers", you have found a plane.

Option 2: Eigenanalysis of neighbourhoods / tensor voting

Suppose you have some collection of 3D points $\mathbf{p}_1 = (x_1,y_1,z_1), \ldots, \mathbf{p}_n = (x_n,y_n,z_n)$. We will assume that these points are a "neighbourhood" in some sense; perhaps they are all points within some radius of a candidate point.

Define the *mean position* $\bar{\mathbf{p}}$ to be:

$$\bar{\mathbf{p}} = (\bar{x}, \bar{y}, \bar{z}) = \frac{1}{n} \sum_i \mathbf{p}_i $$

and the *covariance matrix* to be:

$$\begin{eqnarray}\mathrm{\Sigma} & = & \frac{1}{n} \sum_i \sum_j (\mathbf{p}_i - \bar{\mathbf{p}}) (\mathbf{p}_i - \bar{\mathbf{p}})^{\top} \\ & = & \frac{1}{n}
\begin{bmatrix}
\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})^2 & \sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y}) &  \sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})(z_i - \bar{z}) \\
\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})(y_i - \bar{y}) & \sum_i (y_i - \bar{y})^2 & \sum_i (y_i - \bar{y})(z_i - \bar{z}) \\
\sum_i (x_i - \bar{x})(z_i - \bar{z}) & \sum_i (y_i - \bar{y})(z_i - \bar{z}) & \sum_i (z_i - \bar{z})^2
\end{bmatrix}\end{eqnarray}$$

Intuitively, the covariance matrix plays the same role as the variance in a one-dimensional statistical analysis; note that the diagonal entries exactly are the variances of the three coordinates. But this matrix contains additional information about how the coordinates vary together.

Now let's suppose that we can diagonalise this matrix. That is, suppose there is an invertible matrix $\mathbf{Q}$ and diagonal matrix $\mathbf{\Lambda}$ such that:

$$\mathbf{\Sigma} = \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{Q}^{-1}$$

Because $\mathbf{\Sigma}$ is symmetric, we can further assume that $\mathbf{Q}$ is orthonormal, and so:

$$\mathbf{\Sigma} = \mathbf{Q} \mathbf{\Lambda} \mathbf{Q}^{\top}$$

where:

$$\mathbf{\Lambda} = \begin{bmatrix} \lambda_1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \lambda_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

and:

$$\mathbf{Q} = \begin{bmatrix} u_1 & u_2 & u_3 \\ v_1 & v_2 & v_3 \\ w_1 & w_2 & w_3 \end{bmatrix}$$

where $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_1 = (u_1,v_1,w_1)$, $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_2 = (u_2,v_2,w_2)$, and $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_3 = (u_3,v_3,w_3)$ are orthonormal vectors.

We will also suppose without loss of generality that $\lambda_1 \ge \lambda_2 \ge \lambda_3 \ge 0$.

This decomposition gives you a lot of information about the shape of the points in the neighbourhood. For example, define the *linearity* to be:

$$\mathrm{linearity} = \frac{\lambda_1 - \lambda_2}{\lambda_1}$$

This number is 1 if the points lie perfectly in a line, and furthermore, $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_1$ is a vector tangent to the line.

Define the *planarity* to be:

$$\mathrm{planarity} = \frac{\lambda_2 - \lambda_3}{\lambda_1}$$

This number is 1 if the points lie perfectly in a plane, both vectors $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_1$ and $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_2$ are tangent to that plane, and $\hat{\mathbf{e}}_3$ is normal to that plane.

Using these statistics gives you a basic framework to decide whether or not some neighbourhood of points is part of the same plane or not. The basic idea can be extended to detect junctions using a technique called "tensor voting".

Option 3: Mesh simplification.

A third option is to use the mesh that you have, and simplify it. You can simplify meshes by merging faces or merging points.

One example approach is very similar to eigenanalysis (which is why I went through that in some detail), but approximates each vertex in the mesh as a quadric form, which is essentially the same thing as a mean location and covariance matrix, and then updates these matrices as points get merged. For full details, see:

- Garland and Heckbert (1997), *[Surface simplification using quadric error metrics](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7E./garland/Papers/quadrics.pdf)*, in *Proceedings of the 24th Annual Conference on Computer Graphics and interactive Techniques*, ICCGIT, ACM/A-W, pp 209-216.

Answer (score 1):

If the corners aren't too rounded, you can try to find vertices close to the eight actual corners.

- compute the centroid;
- find V0, the vertex farthest from the centroid;
- find V1, the vertex farthest from V0 (V0V1 is a long diagonal of the cube);
- find V2, the vertex farthest from the line V0V1;
- find V3, the vertex farthest from V2;
- find V4, the vertex farthest from the plane V0V1V2;
- find V5, the vertex farthest from V4;
- find V6, the vertex farthest from the bisector plane of V0V1V2 and V0V1V4 (choose the plane that bisects the largest angle);
- find V7, the vertex farthest from V6.

Every step takes time O(N) and is robust against inaccurate vertices.

Now you have a quasi-cube formed by these eight vertices. You can use them as such but the faces won't be exactly planar. You can use them to build an exact cube, for instance by taking the average distance to the centroid for the size and form a orthonormal frame based on some of the sides (using Gram-Schmidt or the Kabsch method).

For better accuracy, you can use the eight vertices to create separating planes and define eight octants in space. By assigning the point of the clouds to every octant, you obtain eight plane fitting problems.

Answer (score 0):

Just to share what I ended up doing:
First I down sampled my point cloud from 60 million points to 60 thousand points, while keeping the shape of the object as much as possible.
This was done using the opend3D function: pcd.voxel_down_sample(voxel_size=0.05)

After that I used the CGAL - shape detection:
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Shape_detection/index.html.
This gave me a set of regions which represents each one of the surfaces of the object.

Now I can average out the normal values of each region in order to achieve a smooth surface.
If I'm missing something, please comment! Thanks @"Yves Daoust" and @"Pseudonym" for your help.